# bash: fdisk: command not found

Tags: debian, fdisk

I have installed Debian 10 remotely on a server from a live netinstal iso USB over KVM, but then I encounter this strange problem:

```
# fdisk -l
bash: fdisk: command not found
```

However if I use `/sbin/fdisk -l` , the command executes with no issues.

I'm wondering what has caused this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the value returned by `echo $PATH`?

Comment: You've been told how to fix it, but what caused it is that `/sbin` is for system commands that regular users don't normally have the rights to execute (like `fdisk`, for example), so `/sbin` isn't included in regular users' PATHs by default.

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l`, if not work then add to the PATH variable `:/sbin/fdisk`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add `/sbin` to your PATH:

```
vagrant@stretch:~$ PATH="/sbin:$PATH"
vagrant@stretch:~$ command -v fdisk
/sbin/fdisk
```

And use `fdisk` with sudo:

```
vagrant@stretch:~$ sudo fdisk  -l
Disk /dev/sda: 19.8 GiB, 21265121280 bytes, 41533440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa0fd0b1a

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 39438335 39436288 18.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       39440382 41531391  2091010 1021M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       39440384 41531391  2091008 1021M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `/sbin` in your path? Run `echo $PATH` to check. Often `/sbin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin` so check if that is also in the path.
See [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/166403) for how to modify the path.